# How do you remove a list element

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a small program that will jumble up the letters of the alphabet(In simple terms)

I have tried to use things like `list.pop()` or `list.remove()`, But those did nothing

```py
import random


def rand_let():
    i = 26
    alphabet = str('')
    for a in range(1, 26):
        key = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        print(len(key))
        print(key)
        letter = random.randint(1, i)
        print(key[letter])
        letters = key[letter]
        alphabet += str(letters)
        key.remove(letter)
        i -= 1


rand_let()
```

I want it to jumble up the alphabet,
it is, but the way it is doing it will make letters repeat(I don't want it to repeat)

Comment: Shuffle the `key` array and then do `alphabet = "".join(key)`

Comment: I don't think you should get any repeats. Each time you add a letter to `alphabet` you remove it from `key`, so you can't pick that letter again.

Comment: It should be `random.randint(0, len(key)-1)`. Otherwise you'll never pick `A` and you might access outside the list.

Comment: There's already a function to do this in the python library (random.shuffle), but to remove an item from a list by index, use the builtin del (del key[letter])

Answer (score 1):

The `shuffle` function from `random` will save you many lines, and does what you're looking for:

```
import random

alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C']
random.shuffle(alphabet)

print(alphabet)
#Ex: ['C', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting duplicates is that although you have code to remove the letter from the key list, the line that declares the key list is within the loop as well. Try moving the line

```
key = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

above the for loop. Or, as suggested in other answers, use a library to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import string
alphabet = [letter for letter in string.ascii_uppercase]
random.shuffle(alphabet)
print(alphabet)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will just shuffle the list and then print the elements of the list one by one for each iteration of the for loop.

```
import random 

key = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

random.shuffle(key)

def choice(x):

    for letter in key:

        print()

choice(key)
```